# cant fetch table from database in datagridview

Tags: c#, database, datasource

Here's a code for fetching only one column from database table to dategridview. I am getting following error at line no 6 of the following code.

> "No value given for one or more required parameters."

My code:

```
private void marks_entry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
global.connect();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select Name from 5CSEA", global.con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
global.con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your table name called '5CSEA' ? As I remember table name should not start with number...at least for SQL Server. Did you try to use `DataSet` instead of `DataTable` ?

Comment: The usual reason for this error is a missing or misspelled value. Are u sure name of your table is 5CSEA? As per SQL syntax table-name cannot start with a number.

Comment: my database is in ms access..n it is works in it..
and i m getting the output wen i m writing 'select * from 5CSEA'...problem is wen i m fetching jst 1 or 2 column..

Answer (score 0):

@sangram, you can create table like 5CSEA. check your global.con connection status, and use try catch

Comment: please write full error on catch block. 
Then be sure (global.con) connected database

Comment: yep database is connected properly

Comment: very strange. what is database?